# Orthonormalization of basis - Diagonalization of overlap matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

Is it sufficient to diagonalize overlap matrix (Gram matrix) in order to find orthogonalized basis?
Overlap matrix $G$ can be diagonalized as $P^{-1} G P=\lambda$. 
My new set of vectors would be $\tilde{\mathbf{n}_i}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}} \mathbf{n}_i P$, where $\lambda_i$ is the corresponding eigenvalue. 
Can sb explain what is the problem with this method?

Comment: Finding a basis for which the matrix is diagonal is different than finding an orthogonal changement of basis with your diagonal  form (normal  matrices)

Comment: Sure, but here I am diagonalizing a very special matrix. $G_{ij}=\mathbf{n}_i^T \mathbf{n}_j$. The new set of the vectors I constructed satisfies $\tilde{\mathbf{n}}_i^T \tilde{\mathbf{n}}_j=\delta_{ij},$ which confirms that this new set is orthonormalized. It's just I haven't found anyone who would use this method for orthogonalization, which is why i believe there must be sth wrong with it. I just can't figure out what.

Comment: I guess $G$ is symmetric so $P$ is already orthogonal if you want. See diagonalisation of hermitian or symmetric matrices.